# SOLR select request error - Java class cast exception

Tags: java, php, solr, solr4, deep-linking

I am running solr 4.8.1 on the original jetty and quering through a php script. When I query data sorted by price and id on the first cursor mark like "cursorMark=*" it returns the correctly. But when query it again with the next cursor mark I get the error shown below. Although the query works flawlessly when I query with a sort of the creation date instead or the price.

The full query looks like:
`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=age%3A".$age_q."+AND+gender%3A".$gender_q."+AND+category%3A".$category_q."+AND+type%3A".$type_q."+AND+price%3A".$price_q.$sort_q.$rows.$fl.$cursorMark`

The related schema fields are:

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="retailer" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="main_image" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="link" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="age" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="gender" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="type" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="creation_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"   
multiValued="false" />
```

`

The php error returns:
`file_get_contents(http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=age%3A*+AND+gender%3A*+AND+category%3A*+AND+type%3A*+AND+price%3A*&amp;sort=creation_date+desc%2C+id+asc&amp;start=0&amp;rows=24&amp;&amp;fl=creation_date%2Cid%2Ctitle%2Cprice%2Cmain_image%2Clink&amp;wt=json&amp;indent=true&amp;cursorMark=AoIIQpYAACIxNg==) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error`

The log reads:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$LongComparator.setTopValue(FieldComparator.java:652)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$PagingFieldCollector.<init>(TopFieldCollector.java:877)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector.create(TopFieldCollector.java:1183)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.buildTopDocsCollector(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1495)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1596)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1397)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:478)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:461)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:218)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1952)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:774)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the schema columns?

Comment: I added all the fields I created the rest are the ones from that came with the example collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are making a incorrect cast:

```
 java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I think I saw something in the documentation that says you can't do range queries on `float`, can you use `sfloat`

What happens if you remove the `AND+price%3A*` from the `q` query parameter?

> numeric field types that store and index the text value verbatim (and hence don't support range queries, since the lexicographic ordering isn't equal to the numeric ordering):
>
> ```
> <fieldtype name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/> 
> <fieldtype name="long" class="solr.LongField" omitNorms="true"/> 
> <fieldtype name="float" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true"/> 
> <fieldtype name="double" class="solr.DoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
> ```
>
> Numeric field types that manipulate the value into a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form, but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering, so that range queries work correctly.
>
> ```
> <fieldtype name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true"  omitNorms="true"/> 
> <fieldtype name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true  " omitNorms="true"/> 
> <fieldtype name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="tr  ue" omitNorms="true"/> 
> <fieldtype name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="  true" omitNorms="true"/>
> ```

Comment: I tried the sfloat and tfloat and it produces a solr error. Unknown fieldType 'sfloat' specified on field price

Comment: But why wouldn't it error when I first sort it if that was the problem. When I call the function for the first 24 rows it works fine but when I use the cursor mark for the next it errors. When I do this through the solr admin page it works with the cursor mark. I'm stumped.

Comment: The solr admin page  shows the final query. Can you see any differences between your query and that one?

Comment: Found the problem, my script switched the sort on the second query so the cursoMark was invalid and thus the casting error was from float to the date field. Thanks for the help!